# How to combine property and function attributes in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say there is a class `SomeClass` with function `func` which returns `int`. How can we implement a similar interface?

```py
class SomeClass:
    @overload
    @property
    def f(self) -> int:
        return 1

    @overload
    def f(self, x: int) -> int:
        return x


if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = SomeClass()
    print(obj.f)  # print 1
    print(obj.f(5))  # print 5
```

Preferably a solution without external modules, but if this is problematic, it is acceptable.

P.S. `overload` decorator doesn't exist, this is just an example.

#### Edit:

Function overloading is given only as an example implementation, but it is not necessary. The main goal is to implement this interface type:

```py
obj = SomeClass()
obj.f  # returns 1 (without brackets, works like property)
obj.f(5)  # returns 5 (with brackets, works like a normal function)
```

Comment: Python **does not support method overloading**

Comment: There is such a thing as `@overload` in Python, but you can't use it to have `obj.f` be both an `int` and a callable.

Comment: @Samwise right, it is merely for type hinting, it doesn't actually allow for ad hoc polymorphism

Comment: You can also combine it with `*args, **kwargs` to have a method that behaves differently (and has different type signatures) depending on the type of its arguments.  But that still doesn't help OP with what they're trying to do.  That requires significantly more shenanigans.

Comment: dang, it got closed right before I could post the answer to how you actually do this (it involves magic methods on the object returned by the property) :P

Comment: Fine, re-opened but perhaps edit the title

Comment: @samwise question was re-opened;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core of your problem here is that you want `obj.f` to be simultaneously an `int` and a function:

```
    print(obj.f)     # print 1
    print(obj.f(5))  # print 5
```

This is technically possible by creating a callable `int` with the desired behavior, and having your property return that:

```
class SomeClass:
    class TrickyInt(int):
        def __new__(cls, val):
            return super().__new__(cls, val)

        def __call__(self, val):
            return self.__class__(val)

    @property
    def f(self):
        return self.TrickyInt(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = SomeClass()
    print(obj.f)     # prints 1
    print(obj.f(5))  # prints 5
```

This is a lot of trouble to go to in order to implement a very unintuitive interface, though.  I would recommend having this be a regular old method:

```
class SomeClass:
    def f(self, val=1):
        return val


if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = SomeClass()
    print(obj.f())   # prints 1
    print(obj.f(5))  # prints 5
```

Comment: This should almost certainly never be used

Comment: beware the magic!